# Получить значение в квадратных скобках (регуляное выражение)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
test[Test]
```

На строку уже есть регулярное выражение, в итоге нужно получить значение в квадратных скобках в отдельную группу (если оно есть).
К примеру `\w{4}\[(.*)\]` (указанный пример отработает если есть [], а нужно чтобы отработало даже если нет)

Comment: Используйте `\w{4}(?:\[(.*?)\])?` . Какой язык программирования?

Comment: Спасибо помогло